# Django not showing updated data from database

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, mysql-python

I have a django 1.11.4 application running on mysql 5.6.16 on windows. When I add new data or update existing data, the new information does not show up until after I restart. I have tried providing the db_name as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30905621/django-database-data-not-showing-in-application) but it has not solved my case.

How else can I resolve this? 
I am using the default web server that comes with django.
My complete model is as shown below

```
class Member(AbstractUser):

    first_name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('First Name'), blank=False, max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Last Name'), blank=False, max_length=100)
    member_number = models.IntegerField(blank=False, unique=True)
    national_id = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('National ID Number'), blank=False, unique=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=_('Phone Number'))
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name=_('Email'), unique=True, max_length=100, blank=False)
    username = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('User name'), max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    position = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Position in Society'),
                            max_length=100,
                            choices=(
                                ('MEMBER', 'Member'), ('COMMITTEE', 'Committee'), ('STAFF', 'Staff'),
                            ))
    employer = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Employer'), max_length=250, blank=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['member_number', 'national_id', 'first_name', 'last_name']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('member')
        verbose_name_plural = _('members')
        db_table = 'members_member'

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.last_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_full_name()
```

My database connection settings are shown below

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'open_db',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'rootpass',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

This is the views.py class that creates the member

```
class CreateMember(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):

    model = Member
    form_class = MemberCreationForm
    permission_required = ('members.add_member',)
    permission_denied_message = "Permission denied"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        return render(request, 'members/create_member.html', {'form': self.form_class})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        form = MemberCreationForm(data=request.POST,)

        if form.is_valid():

            form.save()

            messages.success(self.request, 'Success, member was added.', extra_tags='alert alert-success')

            return redirect(to='/members/directory')

        else:

            messages.error(self.request, 'Errors occurred.', extra_tags='alert alert-danger')

            return render(request, 'members/create_member.html', {'form': form})
```

Then the form used in forms.py used in the above view

```
    class MemberCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(MemberCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

            self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
            self.fields['first_name'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
            self.fields['last_name'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
            self.fields['national_id'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
            self.fields['member_number'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
            self.fields['phone_number'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
            self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
            self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
            self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.pop("autofocus", None)

        class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
            model = Member
            fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'national_id', 'member_number', 'phone_number',)
```

Then the ListView in views.py that I redirect to after the new member has been added.

```
class MemberDirectory(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView, FormView):

    model = Member
    template_name = 'members/directory.html'
    paginate_by = 5

    try:
        context = {
            'total_members': Member.objects.all().count(),
            'active_members':     Member.objects.filter(is_active=True).count(),
            'staff_members': Member.objects.filter(is_staff=True).count(),
            'members_list': Member.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    }
    except Exception:
        context = {}

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name, self.context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        member_number = int(self.request.POST['member_number'])

        if not member_number or not isinstance(member_number, int):
            messages.error(request, 'errors occured ...', 'alert alert-danger')
            return render(request, self.template_name, self.context)

        self.context['members_list'] =  Member.objects.filter(member_number__exact=member_number)
        return render(request, self.template_name, self.context)
```

Finally, the directory.html template that lists all members on the database.

```
{% if members_list.count > 0 %}
{% include 'members/filters-form.html' %}
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped">
<thead>
    <th>Name</th><th>Member number</th><th>Email</th><th>Phone</th><th>Actions</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {% for member in members_list %}

        <tr id="member-actions-tr">
            <td>
                <a title="{% if member.is_active %}Active member{% else %}Inactive member{% endif %}" href="{% url 'members:member-details' pk=member.pk %}">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-{% if member.is_active %}ok{% else %}alert{% endif %}" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    &nbsp;{{ member.get_full_name }}
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>{{ member.member_number }}</td>
            <td>{{ member.email }}</td>
            <td>{{ member.phone_number }}</td>
            <td>
                <div class="dropdown">
                  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Select <span class="caret"> </span>
                  </button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2" style="margin-top: 0px;">
                    <li><a href="{% url 'payments:pay' member_id=member.pk %}">Make payment</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-member-{{ member.pk }}"> Delete </a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>

{% else %}
    <div class="panel panel-info"> No members were found. </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This seems very unusual. Can you give an example of how data is not updated? [mcve]

Comment: For instance, if I add a new member, then go to the list of all members, the new member does not show up. The same happens when I add a new member via phpmyadmin. The new data will only show up after I restart the django server.

Comment: I have tried switching from mysql to sqlite3. The same problem still there.

Comment: That is not a complete and verifiable example. You should add some code you used to try to add member and retrieve the list. Database interactions have a bunch of steps, and there's no way for us to know what could have happend from a vague description.

Comment: @HåkenLid Thank you for your continued support. I have just added more of the code I am using. Kindly let me know if it is sufficient. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It was really easy. The answer is in the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#all) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated).

Therefore, changing the MemberDirectory listview as shown below actually worked !

```
class MemberDirectory(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView, FormView):

    model = Member
    template_name = 'members/directory.html'
    paginate_by = 5

    try:
        context = {
            'total_members': Member.objects.all().count(),
            'active_members':     Member.objects.filter(is_active=True).count(),
            'staff_members': Member.objects.filter(is_staff=True).count(),
        }
    except Exception:
        context = {}

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.context['members_list'] = Member.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
        return render(request, self.template_name, self.context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        member_number = int(self.request.POST['member_number'])

        if not member_number or not isinstance(member_number, int):
            messages.error(request, 'errors occured ...', 'alert alert-danger')
            return render(request, self.template_name, self.context)

        self.context['members_list'] = Member.objects.filter(member_number__exact=member_number)
        return render(request, self.template_name, self.context)
```

Simply put, the previous listview was using a queryset that contained cached data before changes were made to the database.

Comment: And the primary reason you get into trouble is because you use all those mixins and then do the work yourself. If using a normal [`get_context_data`](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/#get_context_data) approach you wouldn't be in this.

Comment: @Melvyn How would you rewrite the MemberDirectory class using `get_context_data` together with the  `get` and `post` methods?